# Unity: Why isn't my object being destroyed on trigger?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to destroy this object when it collides with another object but it won't remove from the hierarchy. There's no errors, just nothing happens.

```
public class Invader : MonoBehaviour
{

    public System.Action killed; //dont worry about that

    private void OnColliderEnter(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.CompareTag("Laser"))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, kudos for using `CompareTag()`, as most just use `==` which is not efficient. Secondly, nitpicking here, but `this` is not necessary in the `Destroy()` call. Back on topic, Destroy() will destroy a game object, but not in the current tick (aka, the current frame). how do you know this is called correctly? Did you try hitting any breakpoints on it? Normally, a game object would get destroyed (even if `DontDestroyOnLoad()` is called), unless an internal error happens (which *might* not get hit, but those are rare cases in alphas and such). Also, please tell us your Unity version.

Comment: @TheNomad Apparently there's a difference between OnColliderEnter and OnColliderEnter2D ‍♂️ Got it working and thanks for your tips

edit- im using 2021.3.6f1

Comment: there is no harm to use print statements to debug such issues. Just a print statement in the OnColliderEnter method would have shown you that this thing is not getting executed and its not an issue with the if condition, or the destroy method!

Comment: @Loading Thanks- I'll definitely use that in the future

Comment: @Loading I can enumerate the many reasons why someone should not get used to it. Potential 2-3 calls in situational scenarios and then deleting them might be ok, but doing it on a regularly basis and calling "debugging" is not. I am not 100% against it, but due to beginner programmers that choose the easy routes instead of learning and understanding how things work, most will resort to lazy and bad practices which will harm them on the long run, not only in indie projects, but even enterprise ones. Can you imagine having tens of thousands of commented `log("begin func()")` in the Win11 source?

Comment: @Brendan please edit your question and add the solution so that others can see it in case they have a similar issue. Alternatively you can add it as an independent answer. Also good job not giving up and finding the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `OnColliderEnter` should be `OnColliderEnter2D` when creating a 2D game